# How can I uninstall Office 2015 on Windows 10 without going through the control panel?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, uninstall

For some reason, the standard uninstalling procedure through the control panel is not working. How can I uninstall Office manually?

Note: I need to reinstall Office since its installation did not go through fine and it freezes sometimes.

Comment: "Not working" how?  What happens when you tried?  Do you get errors? Anything in the Event Logs? Have you tried simply reinstalling Office overtop of what's there?  Since you are getting freezes and then can't install things, have you done disk checks yet to confirm you don't have file-system or disk problems?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Everything else works fine. Simply when I click on the "uninstall" button in the control panel, the uninstaller won't start

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 apparently, the "uninstall" command lauches a program called clicktorun.exe which is not running when launched.

Comment: When you run the setup from your disk/download, Office may realize that it is installed and will ask if you want to uninstall or repair.  I don't know what has been done to the machine so if the Office install is partially removed or damaged it may not offer you any options.  If you have a silent install (modified install) of Office it may not offer these options either.  Apparently there is a tool for removal here too:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the Office setup from your disk/download, Office may realize that it is installed and will ask if you want to uninstall or repair.  I don't know what has been done to the machine so if the Office install is partially removed or damaged it may not offer you any options.  If you have a silent install (modified install) of Office it may not offer these options either.

Apparently there is a tool for removal here, along with instruction to "manually remove" as per the original question asked.  I would try every other option before attempting to manually remove office:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Answer (score -1):

Don't use control panel for Windows 10. You adjust from the settings menu - please see the following link as a resource. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/repair-or-remove-programs#v1h=tab01

Comment: Hello! Link-only answers are a no-no.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answer(s) and cite any sites you got it from as a source.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Offscrub uninstaller. open a notepad then paste this codes that you can see on this link: https://github.com/PSAppDeployToolkit/PSAppDeployToolkit/blob/master/Examples/Office2013/SupportFiles/OffScrub13.vbs  then save as "anyname.vbs" then double click to execute.